# str object has no attribute '*'

Tags: python, django

I wanna update the password of my user but i have the error

> str object has no attribute '*'

```
if request.method == 'POST':
    form = resetPwdForm(request.POST)
    if form.is_valid():
        email = form.cleaned_data['email']
        passwordNew = form.cleaned_data['passwordNew']
        passwordConfirm = form.cleaned_data['passwordConfirm']
            #actual password is ok
        if passwordConfirm == passwordNew:
            #new password match confirm
            u = request.POST.get('username', '')
            u.set_password(passwordNew)
            u.save()
```

The problem is on the line `u.set_password(passwordNew)`.

Comment: Please show the full traceback.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The `u` is not instance of `User` model as you intended but a string value coming from POST form. What you have to do is to get `User` instance due to what username you got in your form field

```
    u = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username', ''))
```

You also have to handle the situation when there is no such user with given *username*

```
    try:
        u = User.objects.get(username=request.POST.get('username', ''))
        #setting password and whatever...
    except User.DoesNotExist:
        #do something
```

Comment: `request.user.set_password` is probably more appropriate, although its hard to say without knowing what the op is trying to set a password for

Comment: @Sayse `request.user.set_password` for this to work the user should be logged in, or am I mistaken?

Comment: Well the user shouldn't be allowed to change the password for a user they are not logged in as, surely.

Comment: @AKS - If it isn't the logged in user then you've just built in a huge back door. All you'd have to do is essentially post data containing a username, email, and whatever password you can remember easily and you've changed the password for whoever you wanted to.

Answer (score 0):

You can get it as follow:

```
u = request.POST.get('username', '')
NewPassword=set_password(passwordNew)
userobj = User.objects.get(username=u)
query = User.objects.filter(username=userobj).update(password=NewPassword)
```